# Using RFID in multiple windows forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, rfid

Hie there.

I am trying to use RFID tags on different forms. The code I have works fine if in one from.  As soon you add it to another form it stops. I have tried using event handlers to no success. Does anyone know how I coud do this.

Here is my code:

Public Class Form1
    Dim WithEvents phidgetRFID As Phidgets.RFID

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'To reduce code complexity we assume that there is one PhidgetRFID
    'attached to the PC before the program is run.
    phidgetRFID = New Phidgets.RFID()
    phidgetRFID.Open()
    'Defaults for text fields
    txtStatus.Text = "Not Connected"
End Sub

Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    lvPhidgetInfo.MultiColumn = False
    lvPhidgetInfo.Items.Insert(0, "TagID             Count")
End Sub

Private Sub phidgetRFID_Attach(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Phidgets.Events.AttachEventArgs) Handles phidgetRFID.Attach
    'When the Phidget RFID attaches update the form text boxes
    Label1.Text = "Phidget RFID Reader has Attached"
    txtStatus.Text = "Connected"
    txtNumOutputs.Text = phidgetRFID.outputs.Count
    txtSerialNumber.Text = (Str(phidgetRFID.SerialNumber))
    phidgetRFID.Antenna = True
    CheckBox3.Checked = True
    phidgetRFID.LED = True
    CheckBox2.Checked = True

End Sub
Private Sub phidgetRFID_Detach(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Phidgets.Events.DetachEventArgs) Handles phidgetRFID.Detach
    'If the Phidget RFID detaches close the form
    Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    'If the form closes and the Phidget RFID is attached Close it.
    If phidgetRFID.Attached = True Then
        phidgetRFID.close()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub phidgetRFID_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Phidgets.Events.ErrorEventArgs) Handles phidgetRFID.Error
    'If the Phidget RFID is not attached when the form opens show
    'message box and close the form
    MessageBox.Show(e.Description)
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub phidgetRFID_RFIDTag(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Phidgets.Events.TagEventArgs) Handles phidgetRFID.Tag
    Static count As Integer
    count = count + 1
    lvPhidgetInfo.BeginUpdate()
    lvPhidgetInfo.Items.Insert(1, e.Tag & "   " & count)
    lvPhidgetInfo.EndUpdate()
End Sub
Private Sub phidgetRFID_RFIDTagLost(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Phidgets.Events.TagEventArgs) Handles phidgetRFID.TagLost
    lvPhidgetInfo.BeginUpdate()
    lvPhidgetInfo.Items.Insert(1, e.Tag & "   Lost")
    lvPhidgetInfo.EndUpdate()
End Sub
```

I have also tried this and I crushes without reporting an error.

```
    Dim PhidgetRFID As New Phidgets.RFID()
    AddHandler PhidgetRFID.Attach, AddressOf rfid_Attach
    AddHandler PhidgetRFID.Detach, AddressOf rfid_Detach
    AddHandler PhidgetRFID.Tag, AddressOf rfid_Tag
    AddHandler PhidgetRFID.TagLost, AddressOf rfid_TagLost
    AddHandler PhidgetRFID.Error, AddressOf rfid_Error
    PhidgetRFID.open()
    PhidgetRFID.waitForAttachment(3000)
```

Private Sub rfid_Attach(sender As Object, e As AttachEventArgs)
        Label3.Text = "RFID reader {0} attached!" & e.Device.SerialNumber.ToString()
        'Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Sub

```
Private Sub rfid_Detach(sender As Object, e As DetachEventArgs)
    Label4.Text = "RFID reader {0} ditached!" & e.Device.SerialNumber.ToString()
End Sub

Private Sub rfid_Tag(sender As Object, e As TagEventArgs)
    Try


    txtCardNumber.Text = e.Tag
    Dim lastRFIDTag As String = txtCardNumber.Text
    phidgetRFID.LED = True
        ' Throw New NotImplementedException
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("" & ex.Message, , "")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub rfid_TagLost(sender As Object, e As TagEventArgs)
    'Throw New NotImplementedException
    phidgetRFID.LED = False
End Sub
```

Plaese help..

Comment: An RFID device almost never supports more than one reader on the same device.   Move it into another class so you only ever have instance of it or declare it *static*.

Comment: I am using the same reader at the moment but to login in and then for other things within the program. Only one form will work as soon as I try to use it in other form it crushes